# React-admin: How to create user profile form in react-admin v3.2.*?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I've noticed that the official article on how to create user settings (profile) in React-Admin is outdated (https://marmelab.com/blog/2019/03/07/react-admin-advanced-recipes-user-profile.html).

I followed the example and tried to use a new `DataProvider`, but couldn't get `Edit` view working (it just showed blank `Card` component with no fields even though I've set them in a way that's described in the example).

I was searching for several days on how to implement it in a simplest/clean way, but there's a very small amount of information about it.

Does somebody know how to do it in react-admin 3.2.*?

It might be helpful for others who have the same issue.
Any help will be very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: An updated version of the article is available here: https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/12/14/react-admin-v3-userprofile.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Looking at the props passed toreact-admin's  `Edit`, I saw the `record` prop was undefined. It was because the `id` field inside the record returned by the data provider's `getOne` method was different than the `id` prop hardcoded on the Edit component. Once that was set to match, both reading/editing works.

My working code:

```
// remove staticContext to avoid React 'unknown prop on DOM element' error
export const PrincipalEdit = ({ staticContext, ...props }: { staticContext: any; props: any }) => {
  return (
    // `id` has to match with `id` field on record returned by data provider's `getOne`
    // `basePath` is used for re - direction
    // but we specify no redirection since there is no list component
      <Edit {...props} title="My Profile" id="my-profile" resource={b.PRINCIPAL} basePath="my-profile" redirect={false}>
        <SimpleForm>
          <TextInput source="firstName" validate={required()} />
        </SimpleForm>
      </Edit>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how the data is stored by `react-admin` at the moment (haven't checked how it was before). Now each data entry is saved by its id in the store object (the reasons are obvious). I think the best approach is to modify the data provider.

```
if (resource === 'profile') {
  const { id, ...p } = params; // removes the id from the params
  if (p.data)
    delete p.data.id; // when updates there is data object that is passed to the backend

  return dataProvider(type, resource, { ...p, id: '' }) // set the id just empty string to hack undefined as http param
    .then(({ data }) => {
      return Promise.resolve({
        data: {
        ...data,
          id // return the data with the initial id
        }
      });
    });
}
```

This way the backend endpoint could return just the object at the main endpoint of the entity `/profile`. If you do not set the id prop to `''` it will try to fetch `/profile/undefined` because the id prop was deleted from the `params` object. If you do not delete the id prop from the data object when updating, depending on the backend sql query (assuming you are using some kind of db) for updating a record, it may try to set or search by this id.

In the `Edit` component you can pass whatever id you want but something must be passed.

**Additional:**
If you are using NestJS as backend with the Crud package, these `@Crud` params may be helpful

```
  ...
  params: {
    id: { // the routes won't have params, very helpful for me/profile controller
      primary: true,
      disabled: true,
    },
  },
  routes: {
    only: ["getOneBase", "updateOneBase"],
  },
  ...
```